# Hibernate-OGM with XML mapping file

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I couldn't find a way to make `hibernate-ogm` work with hibernate hbm.xml mapping files.

Whenever I try to set the mapping in an HBM file it seems like Hibernate ignores the `ogm` provider and switch back to a JDBC provider.

I used the following example, which works without any issues with using JPA annotation.

```java
    TransactionManager tm = com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager.transactionManager();

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ogm-jpa-tutorial");

    tm.begin();
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Breed collie = new Breed();
    collie.setName("Collie");
    em.persist(collie);
    em.flush();
    em.close();
    tm.commit();
```

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name = "com.redis.models.Breed">     
      <id name = "id" type = "int">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name = "name" type = "string"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The exception I get:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not apply work
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1152)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.impl.OgmEntityManager.persist(OgmEntityManager.java:82)
    at com.redis.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:38)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not apply work
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doInNewTransaction(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.access$200(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate$1.call(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doInSuspendedTransaction(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:412)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.eventstate.impl.EventContextManagingPersistEventListener.onPersist(EventContextManagingPersistEventListener.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:778)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:751)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionDelegatorBaseImpl.persist(SessionDelegatorBaseImpl.java:554)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to perform isolated work
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doTheWork(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.access$000(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate$1$1.call(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doInNewTransaction(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:144)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doTheWork(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:173)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Could you please provide the contents of the `pom.xml` and `META-INF/persistence.xml` files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988913/simple-hibernate-application-not-working-propertyaccessexception-could-not-get

Comment: Arpan I'm not sure how the link you shared is related